# Get Current URL in ember JS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to get the current url in emberJS but I cannot. I am doing this:

```
App.Route = Ember.Route.extend(Em.I18n.TranslateableProperties, {
    actions: {
        didTransition: function (transition) {
            this._super();
            console.log(window.location.href);
            console.log(this.get('router.url'));
        }
     }
});
```

I used to use didTransition because I need to know the current URL when all elements are load. For example:
If I am in home(/home) page and navigate to contact page(/contact-page), I want to know the url '/contact-page'.

If I use **window.location.href** works, but not always. I thought that didTransition was called when everything else is finished, but not.

Why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is nothing logged or do you get empty logs? Just tried it in didTransition and it works fine for me.

Comment: Why do you want to know the URL? What are you going to do with it?

Comment: Hi! I need to know the URL because I have to compare with an local object

Answer (score 5):

`didTransition` doesn't actually have a `transition` argument as your code suggests.

Instead, you should use the `afterModel` method like so:

```
App.Route = Ember.Route.extend(Em.I18n.TranslateableProperties, {
    afterModel: function(resolvedModel, transition) {
        var _this = this;  // keep a reference for usage in then()
        transition.then(function() {
            console.log(_this.get('router.url'));
        )};
    }
});
```

Reference:

- `afterModel`: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel
- `didTransition`: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#event_didTransition

Comment: I'd like to use this suggestion but `afterModel` doesn't fire after every transition. Any other ways to get this info?